# Prefix a value to an attribute using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variable(ImgData) which as the value `<p><image id="image1" name="firstimage" /></p>`

How can change the value of ImgData to `<p><image id="m-image1" name="firstimage" />` using XSLT.

I just want to prefix or suffix **m** to id attribute. Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

My ImgData takes value as

```
<xsl:variable name="ImgData">
  <p><?image id="image1" /></p>
</xsl:variable>
```

How can change the value of the ImgData as

```
<xsl:variable name="ImgData">
      <p><?image id="m-image1" /></p>
    </xsl:variable>
```

As per hr_117 comments I added this to my xslt but the id is not displayed.

```
<xsl:variable name="sam">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($ImgData,'?','')" />      
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$sam"/>
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($sam)//image/@id" />
```

I am able to print the Imgdata value without "?". Don't know why x-path is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: How did you assign the value to the variable?. xslt-1.0 is not able to handle a variable (with xml from xslt file) as node-set. You neat a extension e.g. "exsl:node-set" to do that.

Comment: The xpath should be `select="$ImgData//image/@id"`

Comment: @hr_117 xpath is not displaying anything. I tried <xsl:value-of select="$ImgData//image/@id" />.

Comment: @hr_117 Values are assigned in umbraco to a variable.

Comment: Sorry bad news: This never will work with xlst-1.0. Even node-set does not generate a node set from an string.

Comment: Only way could be with some string manipulation as `substring-before` , `substring-after` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImagData seems to be a string. Therefore the only possibility to do something with xlst-1.0
is like this ugly select:

```
<xsl:value-of select=" concat(
                          substring-before($ImgData, substring-after($ImgData,'id=&quot;')),
                          'm-',
                          substring-after($ImgData,'id=&quot;')
                      ) "
                       disable-output-escaping="yes"
                      />
```

This will only work if thet is only one  id in the string variable. This could also generate:

```
 <p><?image id="m-image1" /></p>
```

**But I would no recommend to it this way.**

Comment: Why you don't recommend the above code. It works perfectly for me. Any reason other than it look ugly

Answer (score 1):

use concat function like concat("Navin", "Rawat") to get output "Navin Rawat"

Comment: I used this but no use <xsl:value-of select="concat($ImgData/id, '-m')"/>. It shows only -m. concat($ImgData/id,'-m') is not returning anything

Comment: You are doing it wrongly. use   <xsl:template match="image"><image id="{concat('m-',@id)}" name="{@name}"/></xsl:template>

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems.
 * Your variable content is not well formed xml, node name can't start with `<?` This  is the start of a processing instruction.
*  You can't access the content of a variable with xml from xslt-file wiht xlst-1.0. This is only possible with a extension e.g. "exsl:node-set".

Try this to access the id attribute of image.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
   extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
   version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="ImgData">
        <p>
            <image id="image1" />
        </p>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($ImgData)//image/@id"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- You can't change the value of a xslt variable. The only thing you can do is to create a new one based on the old one, with changed content.

**Update:** Example to create a new variable with changed content.

```
<xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:variable name="NewImgData">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($ImgData)" mode="new-var" />
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image/@id" mode="new-var">
        <xsl:attribute name="id" >
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('m-',.)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*| node()" mode="new-var">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="new-var"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The content of NewImgData is now:

```
<p><image id="m-image1"/></p>
```

Comment: There is nothing printed because the new content is assigned to the variable NewImgData. To see the output remove the `<xsl:variable ..` : try: `<xsl:template match="/" > <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($ImgData)" mode="new-var" /> </xsl:template>`

Comment: I tried <xsl:value-of select="$NewImgData"/> and your above method also. Nothing works well.